# How to write the HAVING clause with SQL COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) function in Codeigniter Active Record?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, count, having-clause

I am using Codeigniter and am trying to use the Active Record Class for all my database operations.

However, I did run into problems when trying to convert the last bid of the following (working) query into Active Record code.

```
$sql = ("SELECT ac.cou_id
         FROM authorcourse ac
         INNER JOIN course c
         ON ac.cou_id = c.cou_id
         WHERE cou_name = ? // ? = $cou_name
         AND cou_number = ? // ? = $cou_number
         AND cou_term = ? // ? = $cou_term
         AND cou_year = ? // ? = $cou_year
         AND FIND_IN_SET (ac.aut_id, ?) //? = $aut_ids_string
         GROUP BY ac.cou_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ac.aut_id) = ? //? = $aut_quantity
         AND COUNT(DISTINCT ac.aut_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ac2.aut_id)
                                          FROM authorcourse ac2 
                                          WHERE ac2.cou_id = ac.cou_id)");
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($cou_name, $cou_number, $cou_term, $cou_year, $aut_ids_string, $aut_quantity));
```

**Question**: How do I convert the HAVING clause into valid Active Record code? 
I tried using $this->db->having(); and $this->db->distinct(); but failed to combine the functions to achieve the desired result.

My (working) code so far:

```
$this->db->select('ac.cou_id');
$this->db->from('authorcourse ac');
$this->db->join('course c', 'c.cou_id = ac.cou_id');
$this->db->where('cou_name', $cou_name);
$this->db->where('cou_number', $cou_number);
$this->db->where('cou_term', $cou_term);
$this->db->where('cou_year', $cou_year);
$this->db->where_in('ac.aut_id',$aut_ids);  
$this->db->group_by('ac.cou_id');
// missing code
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You code seems quite clumsy. But, you can use having clause in the following way:

```
$this->db->having("ac.aut_id = '".$aut_qty."'", null, false)
```

Comment: If this worked at all, i'm concerned that this would be vulnerable to SQL injection, as the CI_DB_active_record wouldn't push the user-supplied data through CI_DB_driver.escape() as it is all in $k and not $v.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Veekay. However, this does not answer my question (How to convert HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ac.aut_id) = ? ...into valid active record code).